# How to pass Dynamic array to server in SOAP based webservice

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap

im stuck in this terrible problem, I have a SOAP based webservice implemented in Java.The client besides other data is supposed to have "male" and "female" checkboxes so the user can either select one of them or both and the client is supposed to send it to the server to be stored in the database, where it is a multivalued entity, but it gives me Error 500, the failure on Server side, **is the way i pass the array and then use it on server side correct?** if not how could i pass and process it? here is the code for Client, Thanks in advance for your time:

```
private void salvaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    disease=malattia.getText();


    sexarra=new String[sexint];
    if(sexint==1)
        sexarra[0]=sexone;
    else if(sexint==0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bisogna specificare almeno un valore del campo sesso", "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else{
        sexarra[0]=sexone;
        sexarra[1]=sextwo;}
        // System.out.print(sexarra[0]);
        //     System.out.println(sexarra[1]);



        description=descrizione.getText();


        agestr=eta.getText();
        if(agestr.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Il campo età non può essere vuoto", "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        age=Integer.parseInt(agestr);
        if( age<=0 || age>=110){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Il valore inserito nel campo età non è giusto", "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else{

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/soap/servlet/rpcrouter");
                //costruzione della chiamata
                Call chiamata = new Call();
                chiamata.setTargetObjectURI("urn:ServerNeuro");
                chiamata.setMethodName("aggiungi_malattia");
                chiamata.setEncodingStyleURI(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC);

                SOAPMappingRegistry smr = new SOAPMappingRegistry();
                StringDeserializer sd = new StringDeserializer ();
                smr.mapTypes (Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC, new QName ("", "return"), null, null, sd);
                chiamata.setSOAPMappingRegistry(smr);


                //creazione dei parametri

                Vector parametri = new Vector();
                parametri.addElement(new Parameter("malattia", String.class, disease, null));
                parametri.addElement(new Parameter("eta", Integer.class, age, null));
                parametri.addElement(new Parameter("descrizione", String.class, description, null));
                parametri.addElement(new Parameter("sexarra",String[].class, sexarra, null));

                chiamata.setParams(parametri);
                try {
                    Response risp = chiamata.invoke(url, "");
                    if (risp.generatedFault()) {
                        Fault fault = risp.getFault();
                        System.err.println("Chimata Fallita");
                        System.err.println("Code: " + fault.getFaultCode());
                        System.err.println("descrizione: " + fault.getFaultString());
                    } else {
                        Parameter par = risp.getReturnValue();
                        msg = (String) par.getValue();
                        System.out.print(msg);
                    }
                } catch (SOAPException e) {
                    System.out.println("Errore causata da: (" + e.getFaultCode() + ") :" + e.getMessage());
                    msg = "errore";
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println(msg);
            if (msg.equals("si")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La registrazione è avvenuta con successo", "REGISTRAZIONE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
            else{


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Attenzione il utente inserito è gia esistente nel database", "ATTENZIONE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
}                                     

private void femminaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if(femmina.isSelected()){
        if(sexint==0){
            sexint++;
            sexone=femmina.getText();

        }

        else if(sexint==1){
            sexint++;

            sextwo=femmina.getText();
        }
        else
            sexint--;

        System.out.println(sexint);
    }
}                                       

private void maschioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if(maschio.isSelected()){
        if(sexint==0){
            sexint++;
            sexone=maschio.getText();

        }

        else if(sexint==1){
            sexint++;

            sextwo=maschio.getText();
        }
        else
            sexint--;

        System.out.println(sexint);
    }
}
```

Here is the Server Code:

```
public String aggiungi_malattia(String malattia, Integer eta,String descrizione,String[] sexarra) {
    String ris = "no";
    String q = null, w = null;
    String errore = connetti();
    //inserimeto dei dati del utente dentro la tabella login
    if(sexarra.length == 2){
        q = "INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, descrizione, sesso) "
            + "VALUES ('" + malattia + "','" + eta + "','" + descrizione + "','" + sexarra[0] + "')";}
    else{
        q = "INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, descrizione, sesso) "
            + "VALUES ('" + malattia + "','" + eta + "','" + descrizione + "','" + sexarra[0] + "')";
        w="INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, descrizione, sesso) "
            + "VALUES ('" + malattia + "','" + eta + "','" + descrizione + "','" + sexarra[1] + "')";
    }

    if (errore.equals("")) {
        try {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            if(sexarra.lenght == 2){
                st.executeUpdate(q);
                st.executeUpdate(w);
            }
            else
                st.executeUpdate(q);
            st.close();
            conn.close();
            ris = "si";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Errore: " + e.getMessage());
            return ris;
        }
    }   
    return ris;
}
```

This is last lines of Catalina.out it doesn't make any sense to me.I suspect that the Array might be causing it since its determined at run-time, i couldn't find any other way to do it, hints here will be appreciated

```
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm startInternal
    SEVERE: Failed to start "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm/1.0" realm
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1026)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive soap.war
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory axis
    - Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jul 20, 2011 11:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 3780
```

Unfortunately even after changing the code which i thought could be throwing NPE, it still hasnt changed anything. I changed from
         if(sexarra[1]==null){....}

to
         if(sexarra.lenght == 2){...}

I get the following error:

```
      Errore causata da: (SOAP-ENV:Protocol) :Unsupported response content type "text/html; charset=utf-8", must be: "text/xml". Response was:
```

Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 -

**type** Exception report

**message**

**description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error building response envelope: java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.soap.server.http.RPCRouterServlet.doPost(RPCRouterServlet.java:418)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 logs.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what is happening at RPCRouterServlet.java:418? Have you changed any of the default settings of Tomcat? Have you unit tested each of your components?

Comment: I have debugged the client side code, the exception is thrown right after the server responds.I'm not able to debug the server side code,it doesn't contain main method and the client code calls it. I have not changed any Tomcat default settings and it other functionalities works perfectly fine. I believe the issue is with dynamic array sexarra with how its initialized at the client side or how its processed on the server side.Do you think the array processing on the server side is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you're building SOAP requests by hand and not use some kind of automatic WSDL-to-class generator, one that comes with the JDK, Eclipse or NetBeans. This would give you type / structure safety, but I surely see problems in your code, for example

```
if(sexarra[1]== null) { ... }
```

could possibly throw a `NPE` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Unfortunately, Tomcat's output does not make sense to me either, at least not towards your question.

Comment: Exactly it is throwing NPE, giving me back a 500 internal server error. I am using NetBeans, have never hear of WSDL-to-class generator though, i will surely look into it.I'm actually supposed to explain all the code i write to the teacher, since its a university project.What is the issue with my code, could you please explain? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, you should always be conservative and check your inputs. In this case you're directly accessing the second element of the `sexarra` without checking if the array object itself is `null` or if `sexarra.length >= 2`. If you have a WSDL readily available, [then this should help](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html#Exercise_3_1).

Comment: actually i'm supposed to be creating the WSDL from the Java classes later, so unfortunately the second option can't work...

Comment: Then you should look into JAX-WS and the standard `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` annotations that are part of the JDK 6 since a long time. This uses the "code-first" approach where you design your web service in the code with annotations and you get the WSDL generated automatically.